# How do I know if an email was correctly sent on Plone? 'return host.send(mail_text)' always returns None

Tags: plone

Following the [Plone community-managed developer docs](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/misc/email.html?highlight=email) about sending e-mail:

```
try:
 host = getToolByName(self, 'MailHost')
 return host.send(mail_text)
except SMTPRecipientsRefused:
 # Don't disclose email address on failure
 raise SMTPRecipientsRefused('Recipient address rejected by server')
```

...but `return host.send(mail_text)` always returns `None`, regardless if the email was sent or not (the email is being sent actually). So, can I assume if `None` is the result, it was successfull? This doesn't seen right to me. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python has exceptions so does not need to return a status code to indicate a failure. (With C/Unix a return code of 0 indicates success, a boolean true value indicates an error.)

If you need to react to a mail failure in your code, you must include `immediate=True` in the parameters, otherwise the mail will be sent at the transaction boundary and possibly queued. You can then catch an exception using try/except.

Answer (score 2):

That code assumes the send works unless an exception is raised

Comment: That's what I was thinking. But having a `return None` when `if None` returns `False` in Python isn't a bad thing? Am I missing something about exception handling and such?

Comment: Hum, I think If I need this status code, I could do `host.send(mail_text); return True`. If an exception is raised, the value isn't going to be returned. What do you think?

Comment: It's up to you decide when to raise an exception or when to return a boolean value for the success/failure of an operation...this is beyond the discussion about Plone programming and covered in numerous questions related to Python programming on SO...do some research...this is kind of a question about a programming pattern.